# OleDbException: Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbexception

I got an OleDbException saying that "Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement." I got confused if the UPDATE statement is correct or not. In my code, I test the update statement using a button. Can anyone help me? I want to add 1 to the variable in order to increase its value; number of bottles. I am using Microsoft Access Database. Primary id is ID then Unique is room_number.

This is my Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '====test number of bottles=============
    Dim bottlecount As Integer 'variable used in order to increase the value of no. of bottle/s used

    bottlecount = Form3.lblBottle.Text
    bottlecount += 1
    Form3.lblBottle.Text = bottlecount

    roomhold = 1

    Dim statement As String = "UPDATE tblPatientInfo SET bottle_used='" & bottlecount & "' WHERE room_number= '" & roomhold & "' ORDER BY ID ;"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    With cmd
        .CommandText = statement
        .Connection = Conn
        Conn.Open()
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    Conn.Close()

End Sub
```

===after applying the changes========== This is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim bottlecount As Integer = CInt(Form3.lblBottle.Text) + 1
    Form3.lblBottle.Text = bottlecount

    roomhold = 1

    Dim statement As String = "UPDATE tblPatientInfo SET bottle_used = @bottlecount"
    statement &= "WHERE room_number = @roomhold"

     Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand

    With cmd

        .Connection = Conn
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = statement
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@bottlecount", bottlecount)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomhold", roomhold)
        Conn.Open()
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
```

## Conn.Close()

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE` is not allowed to have `ORDER BY` clause. If you want you update to be order, create a subquery of it which contains ordered list for updates. When using ADONet, please make sure your query is parameters. Get used of `SQLCommand and Parameters`. Try this edited code if it will work for you

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim bottlecount As Integer = cint(Form3.lblBottle.Text) + 1
    Form3.lblBottle.Text = bottlecount

    Dim roomhold AS Integer = 1

    Dim statement As String = "UPDATE tblPatientInfo SET bottle_used = @bottlecount " 
    statement &= "WHERE room_number = @roomhold  "
    Using conn as New SqlConnection("ConnectionStringHere")
        Using comm as New SqlCommand()
            With comm
                .Connection = conn
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .CommandText = statement
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@bottlecount", bottlecount )
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomhold" , roomhold)
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch (ex as SQlException)
                ' add message here '
            Finally
                conn.Close()
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I got an error of "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '@bottlecountWHERE room_number = @roomhold'." I am using OleDb

Comment: @CatherineTakishima can you please add a space here `@bottlecountWHERE`?

Comment: @CatherineTakishima don't forget to accept answer to avoid low reputation in the community :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't order update commands.

```
Dim statement As String = "UPDATE tblPatientInfo SET bottle_used='" & bottlecount & "' WHERE room_number= '" & roomhold & "'"
```

Comment: I used Order BY ID because I want to get the latest inserted row in the database. I cant use Order By in update statement?

Comment: @CatherineTakishima You never specified what type of database you are using, so I don't know how to give you an exact answer for that,  but overall no, you cannot order a update. It doesn't make any sense, as an update doesn't return any rows.

Comment: @CatherineTakishima Is the update creating a record through a trigger or something?

Comment: yea through serial port datareceived

Comment: @CatherineTakishima This looks like it has the information you need:  http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record  also John's advice in his answer is great, and you should implement it.